# Empirical Rule percentile?

Tags: statistics, percentile

Back again! This is probably simple, but I also wanted to check my answer, so here is the question:

*The distribution of heights of adult American men is approximately normal with a mean 69 inches and a standard deviation of 2.5 inches. Using the Empirical Rule, find the following: A height of 71.5 inches corresponds to what percentile of adult male American heights?*

I tried to solve it, and I suppose I was close? I got *P* 94, but it doesn't make sense? Anyway, thanks for coming in to help answer this!

---

---

Comment: What is the empirical rule? How did you get $94$ rather than say $50+\frac{68}{2}=84$?

Comment: Well, the Empirical Rule works with only normal distribution curves, which has to deal with the 68%-95%-99.7% within 1, 2, or 3 standard deviations, respectively. I would also like to know where you got the 50 from? Edit: I see now, do you mind making that an answer so it's more visible to others?

Comment: $50\%$ is the probability of being below the central point of symmetric distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As requested in comments:*

$71.5$ is one standard deviation ($2.5$) above the mean of $69$

You know about $68\%$ of a normal distribution is within one standard deviation of the mean, so about $34\%$ is between the midpoint and one standard deviation above the mean and $50\%$ is below the mean

$50\%+34\%=84\%$